# Declaration of method must be compatible with that of interface method - when method signatures are exactly the same?

Tags: php, interface, laravel, laravel-4

I've come across a very strange problem in a Laravel 4 application I'm building, although this question pertains more to PHP than Laravel: **PHP is complaining that these methods are incompatible when both interface & class methods have exactly the same signature**.

It should only complain if, for instance, the incorrect type hint is used, or there are an inconsistent number of arguments, but for some reason this is complaining when everything is done right. I can't see anyone else who has had this problem, can anyone see anything I'm not seeing?

The interface:

```
<?php
namespace Repository;

interface TillRepositoryInterface {
    public static function allInVenue(Venue $venue);

    public static function findByIdInVenue(Venue $venue);
}
```

The repository class that implements the interface:

```
<?php

class TillRepository extends BaseRepository implements Repository\TillRepositoryInterface {

    public static function allInVenue(Venue $venue)
    {

    }

    public static function findByIdInVenue(Venue $venue)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it complain when you remove the type hint ( `Venue` ) from both the interface and the class implementing it?

Comment: It doesn't, however I just realised that the interface is using a namespace so I needed to add a backslash before Venue for it to match. Oops!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems seconds after posting the question my brain switched on:

It was the fact that I was using a **namespace** in the interface, so `(Venue $venue)` was actually `(Repository\Venue $venue)`. Simply changing this:

```
public static function allInVenue(Venue $venue);

public static function findByIdInVenue(Venue $venue);
```

To this

```
public static function allInVenue(\Venue $venue);

public static function findByIdInVenue(\Venue $venue);
```

Solved the issue. Keeping this up in case anyone else stumbles across the same mistake, to avoid headaches

Comment: I'd say the exacly same thing. I has a problem that look much like it, when I was developing a package.

Comment: Oh man I thought I was going crazy - had that same error even though the declaration is a) mundane and b) exactly the same. But I was missing a "use [namespace] as [alias]" declaration. Thanks for updating your question with the solution :)!

Comment: No problem! One of those things that once you know it you will keep coming across it, but actually know the solution as to not waste time looking for one :) Still happens to me almost a year later!